# How to add a strip in iPad as in the image attached?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on an iPad application. In this I have to show some assets (PDF and Videos). PDFs will be shown full screen and thus no need of any modifications. When a video is being played in NON FULL SCREEN mode, a strip should appear below the video which will have thumnails of each asset, and from that strip user will be able to select and play other asset (PDF or Video). Moreover, that asset which is currently being played will have a green color border around it, whereas, other assets will look normal. How can I implement it? please guide. Consider the image attached.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what you need to have is 2 main sub-views.the top view will show the detailed view i.e play movie or open PDf.

the bottom view is for navigation. This view is a simple `UIScrollView` with vertical scrolling disabled & horizontal scrolling enabled. Add thumbnail images in this view & perform actions when someone taps.

Hope this helps.